# Revalidate token Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have created a token using the command init. That token does not was create with the default ttl, and now it expired. It is possible to revalidate a expired token in kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly than yes, it is possible.
Take a look at the official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/).

> The token is used for mutual authentication between the control-plane
>   node and the joining nodes. The token included here is secret. Keep it
>   safe, because anyone with this token can add authenticated nodes to
>   your cluster. These tokens can be listed, created, and deleted with
>   the kubeadm token command. See the kubeadm reference [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-token/#cmd-token-generate).

From there you can use the `kubeadm token generate [flags]` command.

> This command will print out a randomly-generated bootstrap token that
>   can be used with the “init” and “join” commands.

Please let me know if that helped.